# MockMvc and streaming endpoints - additional bytes after stream close

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm using spring-test with spring-boot in a small Scala application. (Apologies for the long intro/short question!)

So far, everything has worked out fine until I decided to modify one of the endpoints to support streaming. To do this, I added the `HttpServletResponse` object to my request handler and copy the source data using Apache Commons' `IOUtils.copy`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/hello"), method = Array(RequestMethod.GET))
def retrieveFileForVersion(response:HttpServletResponse) = {
    val is = getAnInputStream
    val os = response.getOutputStream
    try {
      IOUtils.copy(is, os)
    } finally {
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(is)
      os.flush()
      IOUtils.closeQuietly(os)
    }
  }
}
```

This seems to work rather well. I can retrieve binary data from the endpoint and verify that its MD5 checksum matches the source data's MD5 checksum.

However, I noticed this is no longer the case when using the REST controller in spring-test's MockMvc. In fact, when the request is performed through MockMvc, the response is actually four bytes bigger than usual. Thus, some simple assertions fail:

```
@Test
def testHello() =  {

    //  ... snip ... read the binary file into a byte array
    val bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(...)

    val result = mockMvc.perform(get("/hello")).andExpect(status.isOk).andReturn
    val responseLength = result.getResponse.getContentAsByteArray.length

    //  TODO - find out why this test fails!
    assert(responseLength == bytes.length, s"Response size: $responseLength, file size: ${bytes.length}")
    assert(Arrays.equals(result.getResponse.getContentAsByteArray, bytes))
}
```

Using the debugger, I was able to determine that MockMvc is appending to the response `OutputStream` even though it is already closed using `IOUtils.closeQuietly`. In fact, it is appending the return value of the request handler which is the number of bytes in the `OutputStream` (from `IOUtils.closeQuietly` in fact).

Why is MockMvc appending to the `OutputStream` after it's already closed? Is this a bug, or am I using the library incorrectly?

Comment: Explicitly setting the return type of the request handler to `Unit` seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value from a controller method can be interpreted in different ways depending on the return type, the method annotations, and in some cases the input arguments.

This is exhaustively listed on the @RequestMapping annotation and in the reference documentation. For your streaming case, taking the combination of HttpServletResponse as input argument (you could also take OutputStream by the way) and void as return type, indicates to Spring MVC that you're handled the response yourself.